# Support RTL for only one specific language

Tags: android, kotlin, right-to-left

I have an app with translations in English and Arabic, so I go with `android:supportsRtl="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
The problem is that some users are using some RTL languages out of Arabic that has no translation in my app, e.g. Hebrew, so it shows the English translation with RTL.

How can I avoid that and keep RTL support only when the language is Arabic and other RTL languages' users will get the English translation with LTR?

Answer (score 1):

Programatically, you can alter the layout direction for some languages.

```kotlin
if (lang in listOf(...)) 
    theView.layoutDirection = Layout.DIR_RIGHT_TO_LEFT
```

Or, you can use `android:layoutDirection` attribute.

**some_layout.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
    android:layoutDirection="@integer/viewDirection"

    ...
```

Define default `viewDirection` in `values/viewDirection.xml`.

```
<integer name="viewDirection">0</string>
// 0 is for left to right
```

And also in the `rtl` language resource folder

**`values-ar/viewDirection.xml`**

```
<integer name="viewDirection">0</string>
// 1 is for right to left
```

You have to specify layout direction in all concerned views but some dialog's may still be in `rtl` mode.

It might be worth to check the documentation for **`LayoutInflater.Factory2`**.

Maybe, there is a much simplier way to solve this problem.